# OneNote: Allow my organization to manage my device

Tags: entra-id

I joined an external Teams account as a guest.  I opened one of the OneNote notebooks and now I'm seeing the following:

> Use this account everywhere on your device
>   Windows will remember your account and make it easier to sign in to apps and 
>   websites. You won't have to enter your password each time you access your 
>   organization's resources. You may need to allow them to manage certain settings on 
>   your device.

[image: onenote screenshot]

What exactly am I allowing?  How do I revoke it?  I unchecked checkbox and clicked *this app only*, what did I allow?

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate ["What Does the “Use this account everywhere on your device” Dialog Do?"](https://superuser.com/questions/1389113/what-does-the-use-this-account-everywhere-on-your-device-dialog-do)

To answer your question, since you unchecked the checkbox and clicked "This app only", you effectively only signed in to that OneNote app with your Microsoft account and did not join the organization's Azure domain. Refer to the above link for more detailed information.